# Inconsistent output of zip functions between Python and Java methods

Tags: java, python, zip, compression, zlib

I'm integrating my system with external one.
My system is written in Java when external is writen in Python.
This system requires to compress body of request before sending it.
Below are functions used for compression:

```
def decompress(input_bytes):
    bytes = input_bytes.encode('utf-8')
    deflate_byte = base64.decodebytes(bytes)
    output = zlib.decompress(deflate_byte)
    out_str = output.decode('utf-8')
    return out_str

def compress(input_str):
    input_bytes = input_str.encode('utf-8')
    compress = zlib.compress(input_bytes)
    output_bytes = base64.encodebytes(compress)
    out_str = output_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    return out_str
```

I have developed code for compression/decompression in Java:

```
 public byte[] compress(String str) {
    byte[] data = str.getBytes(UTF_8);
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    deflater.finish();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
        int count = deflater.deflate(buffer); // returns the generated code... index
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    try {
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.decodeBase64(output);
}

@Override
public String decompress(byte[] data) {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    inflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!inflater.finished()) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        } catch (DataFormatException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    try {
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    return new String(output);
}
```

But the output of compression methods is incompatible:
**Input:**

```
test
```

**Output of compression implemented in Python:**

```
eJwrSS0uAQAEXQHB
```

**Output of compression implemented in Java:**

```
��>
```

I would be grateful for explanation of that difference and help how to get in Java solution that is equivalent to those Python methods.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `str.decode` in Python and `Base64.decodeBase64` in Java don't do the same thing.

Comment: Also, `new String(output)` needs to specify a charset (namely, `UTF_8`).  Without it, you’ll get an ugly surprise when you run on Windows.